# Having issue while import openai libraries and create environment

Tags: python, openai-api

i am running this code but having the following error

```
import openai
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

openai.api_key  = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY') 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 4
      1 import openai
      2 import os
----> 4 from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
      5 _ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
      7 openai.api_key  = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

how to install this module? i am using !pip install dotenv command but not getting solution to the error.

Comment: I guess you didn't install the package correctly. Open your terminal in your project's root directory and run the following command: `pip install python-dotenv`

Comment: You are using this in some kind of IDE (Jupyter?).  You have to install the module in the installation of Python used by that IDE.  It may not be the same python you get at a command line.